# Can I use an object property in the SET clause for neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a node with properties that are object i.e

```
name: {
fname: String;
mname: String,
lname: String
}

Match (n: email:"123@mail.com"}) SET n.name=name Return n;
```

I have been searching SO and the documentation without success. The closest I have seen is the {map} but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store a dictionary/map/object as a property on a node in Neo4j, only primitives (int, float, string and arrays of primitives).

However, you can pass an object as a parameter and refer to elements of that object in a `SET` clause:

```
var name = {
    fname: "Bob",
    mname: "E",
    lname: "Loblaw",
}

WITH {name} AS name
MATCH (n:Person {email: "123@mail.com"}) 
SET n.fname = name.fname,
    n.mname = name.mname,
    n.lname = name.lname
```

You can also set all elements of an object as properties on a node:

```
var name = {
    fname: "Bob",
    mname: "E",
    lname: "Loblaw",
}

WITH {name} AS name
MATCH (n:Person {email: "123@mail.com"}) 
SET n = n + name
```